# Does /res/layout/main.xml describe a View or a ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, layout, view

My `main.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Since the root element is a `LinearLayout`, which extends `ViewGroup`, why does `main.xml` get turned into a `View` instead of a `ViewGroup`? For example, in my main `Activity` class, I try to get the number of subviews that the `LinearLayout` contains like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.main);
    Log.v("myTag", "num children: " + vg.getChildCount());
```

but it crashes when i call `vg.getChildCount()`.

What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the LogCat for the Exception?  The Android devs have done a pretty good job of letting you know what went wrong with the Exceptions they give out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`findViewById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) is supposed to take the ID of a view defined *inside* a layout XML file, not the id of the file itself.  Once you have inflated the view, either manually or via `setContentView`, you could get the Layout with it, if you had done it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

By:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
```

Note the addition of an `android:id` attribute and the use of the matching `R.id` value in the `findViewById` call.  It's the same usage as described in the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).  You should then be able to safely cast the result into a `ViewGroup` or `LinearLayout`.

If, by some chance, you want to load the main view separately, e.g. as a subview, use [`getLayoutInflater()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29).[`inflate(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) to build and retrieve it.

Comment: Works super well.. Thanks